# Private component fields nested in Delphi frames

Tags: delphi, components, frames

Here is a quick comparison of Delphi components and frames and at the end is my question.

**Advantages** of Delphi **components**:

- They are encapsulated well. A software that uses components can access only `public` and `published` properties of components.
- All their inner event handlers are available at parent form's design time.

**Disadvantages** of Delphi **components**:

- They need to be installed with some package
- The package is shared between multiple applications even if the components inside are application-specific

**Advantages** of Delphi **frames**:

- They could be placed on a form just like components
- Their `published` properties also can be adjusted in a form
- They are in-app only and aren't available for the rest of apps which they don't belong to
- They are quickly available. No need to install.

**Disadvantages** of Delphi **frames**:

- All of their inner components are directly available in a parent form. If I move the components from `published` section, design-time customizations are broken in the frame designer too.
- If I override the `Resize` method in a frame all the arrangements are available at run-time only. No arrangements at design-time are made.
- If I introduce a new `published` property, it is not available in object inspector.

**What I would like to have** is a symbiotic thing:

- Good encapsulation. None of the inner components is available from the parent form, but all their inner components are fully functional either at run-time or at their design-time.
- Quick availability. No need to install.
- In-app only. No sharing with other apps.
- Their published properties can be adjusted in a form
- All the method overrides (especially Resize method) are available at design-time.

Could you suggest a thing that fulfills these requirements? Or may be some surprising method to work with frames I didn't know about?

It shouldn't be necessarily a frame or a component. If some of other VCL classes fulfills these requirements, I would gratefully accept it.

Comment: I always create the frames in run-time. Then you are always safe that noone modifies the inner components of your frame. But if you want it be available at design-time - there I see only custom component implementation which will store the class name of the frame to construct and via the class it can also iterate the properties.. - but that's something from the sci-fi movie and is too complicated.

Comment: I dont see why the second disadvantage of components is considered a disadvantage.

Comment: This reads like a feature request rather than a question. You know that the thing that you are asking for does not exist.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Sorry, but I don't know this for certain. On my latest "feature request" several years ago people suggested me to try frames which I didn't know about at that time.

Comment: You want to introduce new properties that can be edited in the inspector, and that means that you have to use components that are provided by a design time package. That's it.  There is nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its properties have to be editable in the designer the object has to be a **descendant of `TComponent`**. `TFrame` actually is a descendant of `TComponent`.

Unfortunately, object inspector seems to use structure information from design-time packages only. Thus, you have to compile a design-time package for your custom published properties to show in object inspector.
But that strikes your requirement of *Quick availability*.

Comment: The _In-app only_ requirement could be satisfied by using _Package Magician_ (just google it), which allows loading and unloading the package with the activation and deactivation of the project.